# playing video in objective c

Tags: objective-c, xcode, video

I try this but not work I can hear the sound but I can't see the image..How can I solve this??

in app delegate class:

```
- (IBAction)tanitimVideo:(id)sender {
// create our UnifeyeMobileViewController and present it
video* unifeyeMobileViewController = [[video alloc] initWithNibName:@"video" bundle:nil];
unifeyeMobileViewController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
[viewController presentModalViewController:unifeyeMobileViewController animated:YES];
[unifeyeMobileViewController release];

}
```

in video.m class:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.

NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
NSString *moviePath = [bundle pathForResource:@"debutteaser" ofType:@"mp4"];
NSURL  *movieURL = [[NSURL fileURLWithPath:moviePath] retain];
MPMoviePlayerController *theMovie = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:movieURL];
theMovie.scalingMode = MPMovieScalingModeAspectFill;
[theMovie play];
MPMoviePlayerViewController *moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:movieURL];
[self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:moviePlayer];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using **MPMoviePlayerViewController** instead, very little code to get it working and you can do it all from your app delegate ;)

```
- (IBAction)tanitimVideo:(id)sender {
    NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];

    NSString *moviePath = [bundle pathForResource:@"debutteaser" ofType:@"mp4"];

    MPMoviePlayerViewController *mp = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:[NSURL URLWithString:moviePath]];

    mp.moviePlayer.scalingMode = MPMovieScalingModeAspectFill;

    [self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:mp];

    [mp release];
}
```

Comment: why you call release ?

Answer (score 1):

Look at your .m file-

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.

NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
NSString *moviePath = [bundle pathForResource:@"debutteaser" ofType:@"mp4"];
NSURL  *movieURL = [[NSURL fileURLWithPath:moviePath] retain];
MPMoviePlayerController *theMovie = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:movieURL];
theMovie.scalingMode = MPMovieScalingModeAspectFill;
[theMovie play];

////////// <<<<<>>>>>>>>>> //////////

MPMoviePlayerViewController *moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] 
initWithContentURL:movieURL];
[self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:moviePlayer];

}
```

why do you make 2 controllers (theMovie , moviePlayer) and you setting all in theMovie but running the moviePlayer.

it's should be like this:
    - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.

```
NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
NSString *moviePath = [bundle pathForResource:@"debutteaser" ofType:@"mp4"];
NSURL  *movieURL = [[NSURL fileURLWithPath:moviePath] retain];
MPMoviePlayerController *theMovie = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:movieURL];
theMovie.scalingMode = MPMovieScalingModeAspectFill;
[theMovie setShouldAutoplay:YES];
[self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:theMovie];

}
```

hope it's help.